# Get encypted chat using find was fine but problem is in searching if i search hello then i write full word i want if type h return hello but return [

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, encryption

This is my schema :-
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const mongooseFieldEncryption = require("mongoose-field-encryption").fieldEncryption;

var encKey = process.env.SOME_32BYTE_BASE64_STRING;
var sigKey = process.env.SOME_64BYTE_BASE64_STRING;

courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name:{
type:String,
required: true,

```
},
user:{
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:"user",
    required:true
},
courseType:{
    type:String,
    default:'free',
    required: true
}
```

},
{
timestamps: true,
}
);

courseSchema.plugin(mongooseFieldEncryption, {
fields: ["name" , "courseType"],
secret: encKey,
saltGenerator: function (secret) {
return "1234567890123456";

```
},
```

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('course',courseSchema)

this is my controller :-
getCourse : async(req,res,next)=>{
try {

```
    let name = 'indi'
    const regex = new RegExp(name, 'i');
    const messageToSearchWith = new Course({name});
    console.log(messageToSearchWith)
 
    messageToSearchWith.encryptFieldsSync();
   
    
const result = await Course.find({name:messageToSearchWith.name})


const count =  result.length;

res.status(201).json({
    count,
    message:"get data",
    result
})

 } catch (error) {
    console.log("Err",error)
```

}
},

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My problem i am using moongoose-field-encyption encyption data save  sucessfully and get data is succcessfully but proplem is regex not support in it if i tipe hello then return hello  but if i type h its return empty array[]. please provide solution.